# Stored Procedure concatenate firstname + lastname from multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, left-join, concatenation, string-concatenation

I've tried to search online, but just can't seem to find something helpfull.

I have a stored procedure joining multiple columns (see below). 
Is it possible to concatinate firstname and lastname as fullname?

```
SELECT Tickets.TicketID, 
       Tickets.Aangemaakt, 
       Prioriteit.Desc, 
       Status.StatusDesc, 
       User.Firstname, 
       User.Lastname, 
       Tickets.topic 
FROM   Tickets 
       LEFT JOIN Prioriteit 
              ON Prioriteit.PrioriteitID = Tickets.PrioriteitID 
       LEFT JOIN Personeel 
              ON User.UserId = Tickets.UserID 
       LEFT JOIN Status 
              ON Status.StatusID = Tickets.StatusID 
WHERE  Status.StatusID = @StatusID
```

Something like:

```
SELECT 
User.Firstname + ' ' + User.Lastname AS Fullname
```

Comment: What you have seems to be right. Any specific issue?

Comment: Just insert the Fullname line as you have it shown into the column list for your SELECT Tickets, and you should get what you want.

Comment: Thanks! If I execute the SP it works. Just can't seem to make it work in WPF and C#.
@hatchet

Comment: Can you tell us the error/exception it throws in C#? Maybe it's something about the single quotes (I don't really think so but it's the only thing I have right now)

Comment: You need to change C# code. It will be expecting 'first name' and 'last name' as different parameters

Comment: So if the stored procedure works this isn't a SQL question then. You'll need to tag with the other technologies and provide the relevant code and better description of what doesn't work.

Comment: I thing I'm doing something wrong to get this out of the DB.
See link, maybe someone knows what I'm doing wrong.
https://ideone.com/fork/1sIEQM

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is. Do you get an error? If so what?

Comment: I don't get an error, I just don't know how to get the concatinated to work in c#